# Is there a system where developers don't get the access to the Cloudflare account but can purge the cache themselves when needed?

Tags: caching, cloudflare, cdn

Basically the question. We have recently integrated one of our sites to Cloudflare, at work. The Tech support team are hesitant to provide access for the account to me and other developers, as it has DNS settings in it and it is understandable.
But, we need the access for the account so that we can purge the cache of any live URL anytime we need after making changes to a page on the live server. It wouldn't be feasible to contact the tech support everytime we need to clear the cache, as we might sometimes need multiple refreshes in quick successions. We haven't requested them to switch on 'Cache Everything' setting yet, due to this situation.

So, I would like to know how this is handled in other companies who have similar constraints. What could be the ideal solution for this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They would need to provide you with an [API token](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/api/get-started/create-token/) with *just* the necessary permissions required to perform your job (just the Cache Purge permission for example).

You would use that API token to call [the API](https://developers.cloudflare.com/api/operations/zone-purge?schema_url=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Fcloudflare%2Fapi-schemas%2Fmain%2Fopenapi.yaml#Request) to purge the cache.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Mark. Exactly what I wanted.

I used this [link](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/what-is-x-auth-key/203765/4) method to make it work. It purges the whole site.

Now, I'm wondering how to purge individual URLs instead of purging the whole site at once.